# Are there time limits on when epidurals can be administered?

Tags: pain-management, birth, drug-administration, vaginal-delivery, epidural

I'm not sure if this would be a hospital policy thing or a medical thing.

Is it possible to get an epidural at 9cm or does it have to be administered earlier on?

Answer (score -1):

It is a medical related question, not hospitally related and depends on how the birth is planned.

This is because epidural is just an anesthesia where the drugs are injected directly into the epidural space. The time lenght of the anesthesia is determined by the type of drug used, which have different half life and so different time of action.

ref: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0072751/

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided a few times and unless I have missed it, appart from the fact that epidurals are injected directly into the epidural space, claims made are not backed up. The link is no more than a faq page. Can you please provide references to back up your claims on drug half life, and the fact that it depends on the birthing plan?